# Dictionary subtract issue for its similar array element

Tags: swift

I am trying to subtract two JSON/Dictionary. But the dictionary containing an array of objects is not working properly. Demo examples are given below. My intention is to prepare a new JSON file that property does not exist in the default JSON file. That is for the country-specific configuration I want to put into the new file.

[NOTE: If the value is different in any key of two dictionaries it should not be subtracted and we will consider the first dictionary value for the key. If the item is the same in any array then those similar array items should be removed. That is my main intention. I think it is clear now.]

```
    let dict1 = [
        "FALLBACK": "en-GB",
        "SUPPORTED": [
            "en-GB",
            "fr",
            "de",
            "es",
            "it",
            "hu",
            "nl",
            "pl",
            "sv",
            "tr",
            "ru",
            "da",
            "cs",
            "fi",
            "nb",
            "pt",
            "sr"
        ]
    ]

    let dict2 = [
        "FALLBACK": "fr",
        "SUPPORTED": [
            "en-GB",
            "fr",
            "de",
            "es",
            "it",
            "hu",
            "nl",
            "pl",
            "sv",
            "tr",
            "ru",
            "da",
            "cs",
            "fi",
            "nb",
            "pt",
            "sr",
            "ar",
            "bg",
            "el",
            "fa",
            "hr",
            "ka",
            "lt",
            "lv",
            "ro",
            "sk",
            "sl",
            "uk"
        ]
    ]

    let diff = dict2.minus(dict: dict1)
```

Expected output (something like this):

```
     [
        "FALLBACK": "en-GB",
        "SUPPORTED": [
            "ar",
            "bg",
            "el",
            "fa",
            "hr",
            "ka",
            "lt",
            "lv",
            "ro",
            "sk",
            "sl",
            "uk"
        ]
    ]
```

I followed this subtraction function. All are fine but the problem is during array subtraction.

```
extension Dictionary where Key: Comparable, Value: Equatable {
    func minus(dict: [Key:Value]) -> [Key:Value] {
        let entriesInSelfAndNotInDict = filter { dict[$0.0] != self[$0.0] }
        return entriesInSelfAndNotInDict.reduce([Key:Value]()) { (res, entry) -> [Key:Value] in
            var res = res
            res[entry.0] = entry.1
            return res
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to substract both arrays values right?

Comment: Yes. Other keys working fine except the array element.

Comment: I would convert first dict array value into a Set, and then cicle over second array if a value is already present in set remove it if not add it, if you don't need sort

Comment: Please consider another dictionary element also. Can you provide an example?

Comment: you mean 2 dictionaries can contain different values for same key names?

Comment: Yes. Any similar value will be subtracted. No need to subtract for non-similar values from array, number, string, and any other object.

Comment: @AMIT what happens if your dict 1 have "key1": "bla" and your dict2 have "key1": "blabla" ? what should be the value of this key1?

Comment: If the value is different in any key of two dictionaries it should not be subtracted. If the item is the same in any array then those similar array items should be subtracted. That is my main intention. I think it is clear now.

Comment: With your latest edit the question is now quite different since you have two `[String:Any]` dictionaries you want to subtract and that feels way to complicated to produce an answer for. Maybe you could clarify if there is a simpler path than supporting `Any` in a solution?

Comment: I can't see how this question is linked to Objective-C. Please avoid using irrelevant tags.

Comment: Yes, it is not language specific, if we implement it without any built in function. But I had an urgency to implement it in ios for dynamic json merging and removing unnecessary element.